# Как правильно написать запоминание для фибоначи

Tags: python, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

Написал цикл фибоначи с помощью рекурсии. Подскажите, как для данной функции реализовать меморизацию? Все перепробовал ничего не помогает.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    if n in (3,):
        print(3,)

    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
print(fibonacci(10))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавь декоратор кеша

```py
import functools

@functools.cache
def ...
```

Без декоратора можно так

```
M = {0: 0, 1: 1}

def fib(n):
    if n in M:
        return M[n]
    M[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    return M[n]
```

Comment: В python 3.7 данный декоратор не работает, и мне нужно для задания реализовать метод без использования декоратора. Но большое спасибо за ответ

Comment: Обновил думаю подойдёт